# /etc/localtime not a link

Tags: etc, timezone, systemd

Rather fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10. Have installed Gnome Flahsback which I am currently using. Have updated Date/Time to show Day MM DD HH:MM:SS. That's about it.

Due to another issue I checked `dmesg` and found the following:

```
systemd-timedated[25780]: /etc/localtime should be a symbolic link to a
                          timezone data file in /usr/share/zoneinfo/.
```

Checking it out, it is a regular file and not a link.

```
$ la /etc/localtime
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.2K Jan 11 14:18 /etc/localtime
```

Further there is a link in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` as:

```
$ la /usr/share/zoneinfo/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Oct 23 01:47 /usr/share/zoneinfo/localtime -> /etc/localtime
```

The [localtime manual states](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/localtime.5.html):

> […] Because the timezone identifier is extracted from the symlink target
>          name of /etc/localtime, this file may not be a normal file or
>          hardlink.[…]

and should typically be e.g.:

```
/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Vatican
```

Would it be OK to manually fix? As remove the file in `/etc` and add a link. Any implications?

Have not noticed this on older versions, but a quick check on a previous install, believe it to be 12.10 (only mounted root from an old HDD), has the same issue. Is this perhaps an Ubuntu or Debian hack of some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [reconfigure the `tzdata` package](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges) to set `/etc/localtime` (`dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`). It used to be the case that `/etc/localtime` was a symbolic link (before Debian etch, so around 8.04?). It no longer is, and I can't find anything in the changelogs of the last release listed in the Packages index (10.04).

Comment: So I am perhaps miss-reading this, from man: *"... this file **may not be** a normal file ..."* – do they perhaps mean more of *"might not be"*? I read it as *"should not be"*. Which in  turn also follows the message in logs: *"/etc/localtime **should be** ..."*

Comment: @user367890 In that form, *may not* means *should not*, you're right. But the assumption behind that statement (`/etc/localtime` being a link) is not true, so that statement is not relevant.

Comment: So the answer is to let it be and ignore the log message :), Do not like it but that is the way it is I guess.

Comment: @user367890 The message is because of `systemd-timedated` (if you check, we didn't even *have* [a `localtime` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=localtime) before 14.10). So the right thing to do will be filing a bug on Launchpad, presumably [the `systemd` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/systemd), that this message is pointless on Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 2):

Reported and fixed.

- package systemd - 218-5ubuntu1

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1409594

Comment: Good to know! And thanks for taking the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install **tzdata** as follows, if efforts to set or reconfigure the timezone data fail ...

> sudo apt-get install tzdata

... then follow the onscreen instructions to select your region and city.